# Count and average data inside categories under two types of conditions

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, average, pivot-table

I'm working on Excel with a lot of data and I'm having difficulty with knowing how to sort through it to get some important numbers. I have minimal Excel experience.

Right now I'm struggling with knowing how to get the average in the difference between two columns. The trick is that I have to get the average in difference when column A is less that column B and then, the same when it's more. And all that within a category.

So for example let's say I have 3 categories: Football, Soccer, and Basketball (these are just made up ones).

So in column A, I have: Soccer, Football, Basketball. Then, in column B and C, I have the scores for John and Adam for the last 3 months, respectively. Lastly, in column D, I have the differences between their scores.

So, for example:

```
Category   John   Adam    Differences
Soccer      5      3          2
Soccer      6      2          4
Soccer      3      5          2
Soccer      4      0          4
```

I want to create a table for within each category I have a table like below:

```
                        Nº of cases   Avg. Difference between John and Adam
When John's score is > 
When John's score is <   
When they are equal
```

Is there some type of formula where I can say something like this:

If the category is Soccer (the category being in column A), take the difference between John's score (column B) and Adam's score (column C) when John's score is larger than Adam's score, then calculate the average of those differences? Then, I would use the same formula but tweak it when John's score is smaller.

Additionally, would there be a formula where I can also, calculate within the category Soccer, how many times John's score is bigger than Adam's?

My data is much larger and I can't do this manually.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for some combination of SUMIF, COUNTIF and AVERAGEIF, which let you perform calculations on a range depending on another range. SUMIFS and such are also available if you have multiple criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  A           B       C        D  
1 Sport       John    Adam     Differences    
2 Soccer      5       3        2    
3 Soccer      6       2        4    
4 Soccer      3       5       -2  
5 Soccer      4       0        4  
6 Basketball  20      15       5  
7 Basketball  7       13      -6  
8 Basketball  26      10      16   
9 Basketball  8       11      -3
```

Type in D1:

```
=B1-C1
```

Drag the formula in Column D to all rows which there are values in columns A, B and C.

Create the PivotTable.

Drag Sport to "Row Label" field. Drag Differences to "Row Label" field under Sport.
Drag Differences to "Values" field as: Count of Differences (same way the previous question)
Drag Differences to "Values" field (below Count of Differences), and set the mathematical operation as "Average" of Differences (left-mouse click Differences, choose "Values fields settings" and select "Average").

Give a right-click mouse in cell A5 (see picture bellow) and select "Group" option.
Set "Starting at" = 0; "Ending at" = 1000; "By" = 1000 (as in the picture below). Click ok.

You will have in each Sport, the count (frequency) and average Differences values for two groups:

1. When the Difference B1-C1 is negative; and
2. When the Difference B1-C1 is zero or positive.

The average of Differences when the score is equal will be always zero.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for all the help! I'm discovering how much pivot tables can do